cant compile android project compileDebugJavaWithJavac androidJdkImage .gradle\caches\transforms-3
I have this problem:
Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':project:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\d\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
> C:\Users\d.gradle\caches\transforms-3\59a33ee5905a6b1c51bcbeb16300c0b9\transformed\output\temp\jmod\java.base.jmod

My build.gradle have:
compileSdkVersion 33 or 34
targetSdkVersion 33
gradle:7.2.2
I have tried with no success, removing android studio completly (like this How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?)
also have tried this solution (Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidJdkImage).
And also have tried changing to java 11, java 17, java 18 and is always with the same problem.
